# Constructing a String From a Variable

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a variable in XSLT which contains numbers (like: 1 or 2 or 5 or 7).

I need to construct a string to be displayed in HTML such that the the string is the number of space bars that is in the variable. I need to append this string to a value in XSLT and display it in the HTML.

Any idea how this can be done the best way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want a way to take a number and produce a string containing that many spaces. The way I approach this is to create a variable containing a long string of spaces, at least as long as the biggest number you will be dealing with

```
<xsl:variable name="spaces" select="'                                            '"/>
```

and take substrings of this as required

```
substring($spaces, 1, $numSpaces)
```

If you want something that will show as space in HTML you can use a string of no-break spaces instead

```
<xsl:variable name="spaces" select="'&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;.......'"/>
```

Comment: How do I use the substring method ?

Comment: @HarshdipSingh it's an xpath expression so you can use it anywhere xpath is allowed, e.g. In the `select` of a `value-of` or `variable`